# When I copy /etc/shadow to another system, is it possible to login with the according passwords?

Tags: linux, password, shadow

I am asking, because I generated a live CD using the hash from an existing `/etc/shadow`, assuming I will then be able to login with the corresponding password, but apparently login fails.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's possible if

1. the target system uses shadow passwords, and
2. `/etc/shadow` is not overridden by other mechanisms (via `PAM`, `nss`, etc.), and
3. the target system doesn't hash `/etc/shadow`, and
4. the target system has the same usernames as the source system, and
5. the UIDs on the target system are the same as the UIDs on the source system, and
6. the encryption methods used by the passwords need to be supported on the target system, and
7. `/etc/passwd` on the target system must be in sync with the injected `/etc/shadow`.

I hope I didn't forget anything. :)

The easier (and safer) way to do it is to use `vipw` to save credentials for the relevant users on the source system, then copy them on the target system

Comment: Yes, the encryption methods used by the passwords need to be supported on the target system.  That's unlikely to be a problem these days.

Comment: It’s implied by your #4 and #5, but it might be clearer if you explicitly said that the `/etc/passwd`  on the target system must be in sync with the injected ``/etc/shadow``.

Comment: @G-Man Edited.  Now it's redundant, but oh well. :)

Comment: To move users and their passwords, I found it easiest to create them on the new system, and then `grep` their entries from `shadow`: `egrep "^(jane|joe):" /etc/shadow`. Then do a replace in `shadow`.

Comment: @SatōKatsura Since both systems are the exact same distribution, most of the requirements are definitely met. I still fail to see where things could be going wrong. All I'm doing is `passwd root` on the source system, then copy the second field (everything between the first and second colon) from the **root:** line to the corresponding line in /etc/shadow on the target system. What am I missing?

Comment: @user569825 How would I know without having access to your machine? Hashing, PAM, nss, or one of the myriad things I haven't thought off. Linux is increasingly bizarre these days, and I stopped paying attention ~10 years ago. _shrug_

Comment: @SatōKatsura Nevermind. Apparently there was just an issue in the `sed` command I had used to update the shadow file. Thank you for your answer and explanation.