# how do I set a root password on a dd image?

Tags: command-line, password, disk-image

I have a dd os image, I can mount it and edit files, but the root user, has no password. so then when I burn the image, I can't log in via shh until I set a root password. I'd prefer not to change that. So instead I have to use a uart adapter, login as root and manually change the password.  It would be simpler if I could skip that step, and just modify the dd image to include a root password, but I'm not sure how to do that. Suggestions please.

Answer (score 2):

If you can mount it, and it has an operating system of the right architecture (i.e. same as on the host machine or compatible with the host - e.g. amd64 chroot on amd64 host, or x86 32-bit chroot on amd64 host) and at least a minimum viable operating system in the correct directory structure, then you can `chroot` into it and run `passwd` (or whatever else you need to run).

`chroot` runs a shell or other command as if the directory you specify is the root directory.  In order for this to work, that directory must have its own /etc, /bin, /usr, /lib and other directories containing at least the minimum required config files, binaries, and libraries.

e.g. if you have mounted your disk image as `/mnt`:

```
# chroot /mnt
# passwd
.
. do anything else you need
.
# exit
```

alternatively, just run `chroot /mnt passwd` if all you need to do is execute that one command.

See `man chroot` for a summary of command-line options and, if you are using GNU coreutils, run `info chroot` or `pinfo chroot` for full documentation.

---

BTW, instead of (or as well as) setting the root password, you might want to add your ssh public keys to the disk image's `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.  That would allow you to set `PasswordAuthentication no` before you even deploy the image.

Comment: and what if its not the same architecture?

Comment: 1. Add your public key(s) to root's authorized_keys file (optionally change the password over ssh later). 2. Or boot it up on an emulator and change the passwd while it's running on that. 3. Create a dummy account with the password you require and copy just the password from that /etc/shadow entry to root's /etc/shadow entry in the disk image. See [When I copy /etc/shadow to another system, is it possible to login...?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/401420) for some caveats. If you're using the same root password on multiple copies of the disk image, copy the password from a running image